# RSpec View Spec - how to render partial with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Have a routes.rb file which looks like the following:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

Trying to test the rendering of a _comment partial correctly, here is my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'rendering the comment partial' do
  let!(:comment) { create(:comment, name: "Richard Stokes")}
  it "displays the comment's username" do
    render partial: 'comments/comment.html.haml', locals: { comment: comment }
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Richard Stokes")
  end
end
```

However when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: render partial: 'comments/comment.html.haml', locals: { comment: comment }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000669f0b8>:0x000000067249e8>
```

Adding an additional, non-nested `resources :comments` to my routes fixes the issue, but I would like to be able to leave my routes as they were originally and instead just render the comment partial through the correct path. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: well what is the path in the partial, why is it wrong? what is the 'correct' path as you intended?

Comment: The partial is normally rendered through the post_path - a posts comments are rendered as a collection alongside it. I'm just trying to render the partial on it's own, passing in the necessary local variable, to test that certain content is present when rendered.

Comment: thats not what I meant. Obviously your partial is referencing `comments_path`, which you think is wrong. What should it be, and why are you then not referencing that instead?

Comment: shallow by default means: index, new and create. That's why you get the error that comments_path doesn't exist. post_comments_path will exist though...